# mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server through Apache

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I'm trying to connecto to a MSSQL server through mssql_connection from Apache in a CentOS. This is the script:

```
<?php

$link = mssql_connect('10.10.10.10', 'XXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYY');

if (!$link || !mssql_select_db('Utilities', $link)) {
    echo mssql_get_last_message();
}
```

If I run this script through command line, I get the connection. But when I access it as a page through Apache, I get the error

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: 10.10.10.10 in /var/www/html/pruebas/pruebas/sql.php on line 4
```

At the beginning I thought the problem was that, being the server behind a proxy, but even when I don't configure my account to use that proxy, I still can connect through the command line but not through apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's due to SELinux preventing Apache (and therefore all Apache modules) from making remote connections by default.

To check that run

```
$ getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_network_connect
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
```

and to enable them if they are not on, do

```
$ setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
$ setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

If it's not that, then check that you have php-mssql installed to begin with

```
yum install php-mssql
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly! Thank you very much! I always forget about pesky SELinux!